# i can't get response from openweathermap api when coorinate equal or greater than 90

Tags: android, json, api

i cant get a response from openweathermap Api if one coordinate is equal than or bigger than 90 and it return message says x is not a float.

[screenshot for error response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jA8t1.png)

[screenshot for right response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0UZ4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latitude ranges from -90 to 90, and longitude from -180 to 180. Out of those bounds it is not a valid coordinate.
So the fact you received an error makes perfect sense. Though the error could be more descriptive such as 'value for x is not valid'.

---

You can find more information about latitude longitude coordinates with a simple google search. For example here on http://www.latlong.net/ (emphasis mine):

> The latitude has the symbol of phi, and it shows the angle between the straight line in the certain point and the equatorial plane. **The latitude is specified by degrees, starting from 0° and ending up with 90°** to both sides of the equator, making latitude Northern and Southern. The equator is the line with 0° latitude. The longitude has the symbol of lambda and is another angular coordinate defining the position of a point on a surface of earth. The longitude is defined as an angle pointing west or east from the Greenwich Meridian, which is taken as the Prime Meridian. **The longitude can be defined maximum as 180° east from the Prime Meridian and 180° west from the Prime Meridian**.

Answer (score 1):

Remember: Latitude from -90 to 90. Longitude from -180 to +180.
Hope it Helps.